# Can Spark parallelize nested?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I run the following code on a 60-code EC2 instance

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import time, md5
workers_count = 10
sc = SparkContext("local[%s]" % workers_count, "App Name")
max_num = 50000000
start_time = time.time()
first_item = sc.parallelize(xrange(max_num)).map(lambda n: (n, md5.md5(str(n)).hexdigest())).reduce(lambda a,b: a if a[1] > b[1] else b)
end_time = time.time()
print("sorting took took %s seconds with %s workers" % (end_time-start_time, workers_count))
```

with 1 worker it took 52 sec.
with 2 workers it took 26 sec.
with 4 workers it took 13 sec
with 8 workers it took 6 sec
with 16 or more workers it took 4 sec (more or less)

The above code is the inner-part, and it needs to run a few million times

From the above I understand that there is a limit to how much will parallelization improve the performance, which is OK, but since I'm using a 60-cores machine, and I want it to make the best usage of the cores, I want each loop to use 8 cores, having 7 loops running simultaneously.

Is it possible to define for each function how many cores it will use?

Answer (score 0):

> Can Spark parallelize nested?

It cannot. Spark parallel execution has to be flat.

You can submit multiple concurrent jobs **using separate threads**. For example using [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) with threading and `numSlices`:

```
import hashlib
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def run(sc, numSlices=8):
    return sc.range(0, max_num, numSlices=numSlices) \
        .map(lambda n: (n, hashlib.md5(str(n)).hexdigest())) \
        .reduce(lambda a,b: a if a[1] > b[1] else b) 

Parallel(n_jobs=7, backend="threading")(delayed(run)(sc) for _ in range(7))
```

Comment: I agree that this will solve the problem with a local single machine, but the idea with spark is that it can also work with a multi-node cluster, and this solution will not scale the spark-way

Comment: It will work as expected as long as there is enough resources in the cluster.

Comment: The question was about spark, not about how to use other ways to do the job, and I also think that if I add another level of nesting, things might get complicated and ugly